# I just installed UBUNTU on Mac Book air and getting the following error at re boot

Tags: boot, mac, macbook

I have attempted to install this and said to remove the bootable usb drive and when I did It shows this code I have no idea what is wrong or what to do.

I tried to restart my mac book air and this is the code I am getting , any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Image:

[image]

Here is the error I am getting in text:

```
dnd_bus_dump_dar registers : dar_clk_ctrl (0xa08 :0x10300400 ) dar_pwr_ctrl ( 0xa0c 0x30000) dar_instat (0xa10:0x0) GNU GRUB version 2.06. dhd_bus_dump_dar_registers: dar_errlog (0xa60:0x0) dar_erraddr (0xa64:0x0) dar_pci Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.  For the first word, TAB lists possible comand line completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.  dhd_send-d2h_ringcreate ringid: 3 idx: 46 max _h2d: 43 dhd_prot_process_d2h_ring_create_complete ring create Response status - 0 ring 3 grub> xfffc info buffer post after ring create 
wl_ioctl: dhd_wl_ioctl_cmd failed. cmd 263, ret -14, ifidx = 0
wl_iovar wlIoctl failed.  name sku_override , ret -14
dhd_bus_start_phase2 : SKU override fails, err= -14

wlc_ver_major 10 wlc_ver_minor 0dhd_sync_with_dongle : GET_REVINFO device 0x4488 , vendor 0x14e4 , chipnum 0x4377
dhd_syncc_with_dongle; GET RxBuf post FAILED, use default 1920
Firmware version =wl0: Mar 9 2021 08:41:19 version 16.20.308.0.3.6.99 FWID 01-5b2fe66e

Release FW, Set PM=2 mpc=1 
wl_ioctl :dhd_wl_ioctl_cmd failed.  cmd 262, ret -23, ifidx = 0
wl)iovar wlIoctl failed.  name scan_ver, ret -23
dhd_preinit_ioctls: Disabled Rx A-MSDU
```

Comment: please post the contents of your error as text, not just an image.

Comment: please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1410578/edit) your question to place that relevant information *in the body of the question*